# Querying particular static resource from complete pages in Org

Tags: static-resources

I need to check for a particular resource in different VF pages.Normal method will be opening each page and checking for the static resource(Image/JS files) but is there any other probable method ??

Can't we directly query from console where a static resource is used ?? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata API can be used. There's also a free tool on the App Exchange. Is called [Metadata Search](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI) that will allow you to search your org for metadata strings to find where they're located including within the code inside triggers, classes, object fields, etc that have a reference to them. You might also want to look at [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) which has capabilities for documenting what's in your org, including static resources, and is also free. However, I don't believe it has the same level of extensive search capabilities.

Comment: or could use Eclipse IDE and click Search for the staticResource name